# How to handle Activity resume events in Xamarain using AndroidGameView

Tags: android, opengl-es, xamarin.android

What is the best way to properly handle activities being paused / resumed when using the `AndroidGameView` class?

Whenever an activity gets paused all OpenGL textures get cleared, requiring them to be reloaded by the view. It appears that the `GLSurfaceView`([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html)) class has the appropriate machinery to properly handle these events. (By overriding `onResume`.)

How is this supposed to work with the `AndroidGameView` ([link](http://docs.monodroid.net/?link=T%3aOpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGameView%2f%2a)) class? (Does the Android game view simply not support this?) The class appears to have the appropriate hooks (specifically `Resume`). However, when `Resume` is called the `GraphicsContext` hasn't been set yet.

During `Resume` calling `MakeCurrent()` throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation requires a GraphicsContext, which hasn't been created yet.
```

If I put a call to `CreateFrameBuffer` before `MakeCurrent()`, you get a similar error:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Make sure the SurfaceView or associated SurfaceHolder has a valid Surface
```

When should you load/reload any game-specific textures in response to the Activity's `OnResume` callback when using an `AndroidGameView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question/answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/workaround-to-losing-the-opengl-context-when-android-pauses) explains the problem with opengl-es on android when pausing/resuming very well

Comment: This is not a valid answer! The link point to an article that helps who develop in "pure" Android (java). What Chris asked is how to handle this in Mono4Android (Xamarin) I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the link is marked as valid answer. That solution is valid when developing with "pure" Android in java not using Xamarin Mono4Android (Monodroid) API.

I've found a soultion to this question.

The best way to handle this is to relase restore textures when the OpenGL context (and related surface) is being created/destroyed.

In Mono4Android you should use those override methods into the AndroidGameView

```
override void CreateFrameBuffer()
{
    if(checkIfResourceWhereLost)
    {
       checkIfResourceWhereLost = false;
       // Code to RESTORE your textures
    }
}

override void DestroyFrameBuffer()
{
    checkIfResourceWhereLost = true;
    // Code to RELEASE all textures
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activities have some nice methods for handling such things. OnStart, OnRestart, OnStop and so on. You should be able to override them and do your stuff there.